# Persistant pendrive already full?

Tags: partitioning, usb

I made a persistant pendrive that has a 4GB persistant partition, however it seems to be full now that I've installed some packages... But that doesn't seem to be the case since I have plenty of available space. Bear in mind that I'm a newbie at linux.

```
    Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     784M  2.0M  782M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1      vfat       15G  5.9G  8.5G  41% /cdrom
/dev/loop1     squashfs  1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   3.9G  3.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /tmp
/dev/loop2     squashfs   87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop3     squashfs  141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop4     squashfs  2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop6     squashfs  3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop8     squashfs   35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop5     squashfs   13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop7     squashfs   15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
tmpfs          tmpfs     784M   12K  784M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs          tmpfs     784M   12K  784M   1% /run/user/999
```

Comment: The persistent partition is the filesystem called `/cow`, which is full according to the output. Keep in mind that every change will be written to it, including system updates.

Comment: Oh okay! Thought it was udev. My bad

Comment: @danzel Sounds like an answer instead of a comment.  if you post an answer and ping me, I'll come back and upvote!

Comment: Never do an update to a persistent drive, it will fill casper-rw and the drive will not boot. If you want the latest and greatest do a Full install to flash drive, it is both updateable and upgradeable. Just unplug your hard drive and install to flash drive as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updatable and Upgradeable Ubuntu Flash Drive

Everything that gets saved to a persistent flash drive gets saved to the casper-rw persistence file or partition.

Never do an update to a persistent drive, it will fill casper-rw and the drive will not boot.

If you want the latest and greatest do a Full install to flash drive, it is both Updatable and Upgradeable.

Just unplug your internal hard drive and install to flash drive as you would to internal hard drive.

Once booted to the flash drive with HDD plugged back in do a sudo update-grub to get the internal OS added to the flash drive grub menu.